# How do I know which line is generating SEGFAULT in OpenMPI?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, valgrind, openmpi

I am running a barrier program wherein I give number of processes using `-np` option. My program runs fine with 1 process but SEGFAULTS when the number is increased. I want to know what line is causing the memory fault.

I initially tried `valgrind mpirun -np 2 tournament 2` but it just give the following output:

```
[ubuntu:14556] *** Process received signal ***
[ubuntu:14556] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[ubuntu:14556] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[ubuntu:14556] Failing at address: 0x7fff0000005a
[ubuntu:14556] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0xfbb0) [0x7fe3f5c4dbb0]
[ubuntu:14556] [ 1] tournament() [0x40115a]
[ubuntu:14556] [ 2] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7fe3f5897de5]
[ubuntu:14556] [ 3] tournament() [0x4009d9]
[ubuntu:14556] *** End of error message ***
[ubuntu:14557] *** Process received signal ***
[ubuntu:14557] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[ubuntu:14557] Signal code:  (128)
[ubuntu:14557] Failing at address: (nil)
[ubuntu:14557] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0xfbb0) [0x7f23c81e4bb0]
[ubuntu:14557] [ 1] tournament() [0x400f61]
[ubuntu:14557] [ 2] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7f23c7e2ede5]
[ubuntu:14557] [ 3] tournament() [0x4009d9]
[ubuntu:14557] *** End of error message ***
```

Then I thought that I need to generate the symbol table for that so I gave: `mpicc tournament.c -o tournament -fopenmp -lm -g`. Still I get the same output for valgrind.

How do I know which line is giving me `SEGFAULT` using Valgrind with OpenMPI?

Comment: Did you try to recompile the library with the `-g` option too?

Comment: It looks like the problem might not be in MPI but in your program. Are you getting core dumps?

Comment: @doukremt - I don't know about that. How do I do that?

Comment: @WesleyBland - No. I don't get core dumps.

Comment: Set `ulimit -c unlimited` to get the core dumps (you will need to compile your applications and libs with `-g`) and the open that with gdb.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about recompiling Open MPI with `-g`. You're probably fine just looking at your application. You're not going to be able to debug Open MPI anyway.

Comment: @TheRookierLearner: Well, find the source and edit the makefile accordingly. Of course, the idea isn't to debug the library but 1°) to ensure the bug is effectively in your code (so that you don't bang your head against the wall for nothing); and 2°) because you will get a full stack trace including the library calls, which will make the debugging a lot easier (you can know which function fails); 3°) if you still don't get it, you can post the stack trace in the relevant forums, which will help people helping you. I'd also try to use another compiler; clang is very good at indicating errors.